# Subsribe to InlineGraphicElement mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

How can I implement this simple thing without getting list of all gaphic elements and adding listner to each? I can listen for mouse click event and get target as Loader which has parent.parent property as TextLine but I can't get InlineGraphicElement reference from it. Is there any functionality to determine which float element is under mouse pointer?

Here is my code:

```
findElement(textarea.textFlow);    
private function findElement(group:FlowGroupElement):void{    
    for (var i:int = 0; i < group.numChildren; i++) {
        var element:FlowElement = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (element is InlineGraphicElement) {      
            var link1:InlineGraphicElement = element as InlineGraphicElement;
            link1.graphic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,someLinkClickHandler);    
        }
    }
}


public function someLinkClickHandler(eve:Event):void
{
    Alert.show((eve.target).parent.parent); //Here I need source of clicked InlineGraphicElement    
}
```

Comment: can you show some code? what is a float element? do you mean `DisplayObject`? or [FlowElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/FlowElement.html) ?

Comment: Check if `getObjectsUnderPoint()` is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but getObjectsUnderPoint() is returning object loader. But I need clicked InlineGraphicElement. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: You can use it recursively, if a given object is any kind of `DisplayObjectContainer`, convert the point into its coordinate system and call `getObjectsUnderPoint()` again. Eventually you'll find the nested `InlineGraphicElement`s.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a library like HtmlAgilityPack or CsQuery to scrape HTML from a website. I'd recommend CsQuery as it has a familiar jQuery like syntax for scraping elements.

They also have NuGet packages to easily install them in a project.